# Django : get() returned more than one

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I have trouble to get my data from DB.

Basically one teacher can create more no of `class_room` each class_room contains a `title` and it has more number of `students`.

**models.py**

```
class class_room(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'classroom')
    title = models.charField(max_length=50)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name= 'commits',symmetrical=FAlSE)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    Total_class = class_room.objects.get(user = user)
    students_list = Total_class.students.all()
    class_name = Total_class.title.all()
    return render(request,'trial/index.html,{'Total':Total_class ,'no':students_list, 'class_name ':class_name  )
```

When i try to execute this code. i get this error **get()  returned more than one**

Then i removed **get()** bcoz the user has more number of `class_room` so i put **filter()** After that i get **'QuerySet'object has no attribute 'students'**

Any help appreciated :(

Comment: The problem is you have two `class_room` objects with same `user`. That's why `get()` is returning two objects. You need to take care of that, first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple objects for model `class_room` in the database, with the same `user`. Either you need to enforce the uniqueness to the `user` attribute in the models.

Or, you can get the students attribute of the first object in the query like,

```
Total_class = class_room.objects.filter(user = user).first()
students_list = Total_class.students.all()
```

or using index,

```
Total_class = class_room.objects.filter(user = user)[2] 
                                                    #any element.
```

**EDIT**

As per the request of OP, I think the required queryset would be,

```
student_list = User.objects.filter(class_room__user=request.user)
```

Comment: hi zaidfazil  i tried ur answer it is not solving.it read only one class.rest of classes are not showing. i need total

Comment: Do you have multiple class rooms with same user?? And you want the list of all students in all those class rooms?? is it?

Comment: one user have multiple class room and each class_room have one title & multiple students.so i want to display the title and corresponding students.

Comment: For a single class or all classes?

Comment: All classes zaidfazil .. I guess it is not possible .. what about your view zaid ?